# How can I replicate 'skid marks' using HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I've been creating a little experiment in HTML5 Canvas of a car with some basic movement, here it is: (arrow keys to move the car)

http://jsfiddle.net/mpxML/27/

The think I've been trying to figure out is the best way to create skid marks. If you hold the up key and turn you can see it creates some marks, but if you do it again, they link together. Obviously the way I am doing it isn't ideal. It's pushing the co-ordinates to an array and then using lineTo to link up those co-ordinates.

Problems:
    - The lines link up
    - Pushing cordinates to an array to remember skids may not be the best method
    - I've only got one line, so when I add another, the performance will suffer futher.

What would you advise?

Sneaky question: Instead of having a fixed background, what's the best way to make the scene 'pan'.

Thanks,
Henry

Comment: Why don't you reset the array after each skid is complete?

Comment: Oh. Those kind of skid marks. No idea then! :)

Comment: Just off the top of my head. Can you have a separate, invisible canvas, to which you draw the skidmarks on, which you then draw below the moving elements on every draw cycle? This way, you don't need to keep track of the skidmark positions, and will not need to redraw them on every frame. (This is assuming there's a fast way to merge two canvases. I really don't know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/mpxML/34/.

I added `MIN_DIST_TO_DRAW_SKID` variable. If two points in `skidMarks` are farther than that value, the canvas does not draw a line(just call a `moveTo` method).

This is part of code which I made changes:

```
// here
var MIN_DIST_TO_DRAW_SKID = 30;

function drawStageObjects() {

    if(car.drift > 30 || car.drift < -30) {
        skidMarks.push(car.x, car.y);
    } else {
    }

    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(skidMarks[0],skidMarks[1]);
    for(var i=0; i < skidMarks.length; i = i + 2) {

        skidPoint = Math.abs(skidMarks[(skidMarks.length-4)]) - Math.abs(skidMarks[(skidMarks.length-2)]);

        // here
        var dist = Math.sqrt((skidMarks[i] - skidMarks[i - 2]) * (skidMarks[i] - skidMarks[i - 2])
                 + (skidMarks[i + 1] - skidMarks[i - 1]) * (skidMarks[i] - skidMarks[i - 1]));

        if(skidPoint > 20 || dist > MIN_DIST_TO_DRAW_SKID) {
            context.moveTo(skidMarks[i], skidMarks[i + 1]);
        } else {
            context.lineTo(skidMarks[i],skidMarks[i + 1]);
        }

        $('#stats').html(skidPoint);
        //$('#stats').html(skidMarks[(skidMarks.length-4)] + "," +skidMarks[(skidMarks.length-2)]);
    }

    //....
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. The fiddle doesn't seem to be working though :S does it work for you? Thanks

Comment: @Henryz I added code I changed. If the jsfiddle is not working, you may try with that code.

Comment: @Henryz Hey, what's the problem? Why don't you give me any feedback?

Comment: Hey, sorry. Been away from the computer. The skid works well, it has a small issue where it still sometimes joins, but I think I may be able to figure it :)